# Code throwing error after it was working fine before

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def main():
    numbers = [
    'No',
'One',
'Two',
'Three',
'Four',
'Five',
'Six',
'Seven',
'Eight',
'Nine'
'Ten' ]
text_one = 'green bottles\nHanging on the wall'
text_two = "\nAnd if one green bottle\nShould accidentally fall\nThere'll be"
# Each iteration of this loop prints one verse of the song

for i in range(10, 0, -1):         
    file=open('ten.txt', 'a')
    file.write(numbers[i]+' ')
    file.write(text_one+' ')
    file.write(numbers[i]+' ')
    file.write(text_one+' ') 
    file.write(text_two+' ')
    file.write(numbers[i-1]+' ')
    file.write(text_one+' ')
    file.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 32, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 22, in main
builtins.IndexError: list index out of range
```

this was working previosly but now its throwing an error can anyone see where i messed up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be missing a comma for your last entries:

```
'Nine' #<- here
'Ten' ]
```

Once you see an error where you are indexing out of a range you could easily test whether if your list is of the required length by printing the length or debugging this.